# Android webview onTouch issue

Tags: android, webview, touch

OK, so I have a HTML5 website which is wrapped in an Android WebView. On the home page of this website I have a button having the coordinates x and y. Say I click the button from the webview - now comes the strange part - if the new page that gets loaded has a button that is in the same position as the first button (x and y coordinates) this button gets pressed too ! I'm thinking it's because of the onTouch method but I was not able yet to find a decent fix.

Any one came across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was because of the jQuery plugin - I was using both the standard and the mobile version.